# Checking if a template parameter have Random Access Iterator or not

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, template-meta-programming

I'm completely new to metaprogramming, and I have some issue.
I want to write a container which has different inner representation, and uses a different algorithm if the passed `Container` has `Random Access Iterator`. However, I don't know how to check it.

UPDATE: Right now i'm trying with the following:

```
template <typename Container>
struct HaveRandomAccessIterator
{
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template <typename C>
    static yes& test (typename std::random_access_iterator_tag*);
    template <typename>
    static no& test (...);

    static const bool value = sizeof(test<std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator*>::iterator_category*>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

However it give me true value for std::list, and i get compile error, because in that case i use operator[]

Can someone explain me how can I check it correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `HaveRandomAccessIterator` template is overly complicated, there are simpler ways of achieving the same result.

One standard way to change an algorithm on the basis of the iterator type is tag-dispatch:

```
//First, a helper type alias
template<typename Container>
using IteratorCategoryOf =
    typename std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator>::iterator_category;

template<typename Container>
void algorithm(Container &c, std::forward_iterator_tag) {
    //do generic version of algorithm
}

template<typename Container>
void algorithm(Container &c, std::random_access_iterator_tag) {
    //do random-access version of algorithm
}

template<typename Container>
void algorithm(Container &c) {
    algorithm(
        c,
        IteratorCategoryOf<Container>());
}
```

Alternatively, you can use SFINAE through `std::enable_if`. I suspect this is what you were aiming to do, but `HaveRandomAccessIterator` can be written in terms of `std::is_base_of`, which is far simpler:

```
template<typename Container>
using HaveRandomAccessIterator =
    std::is_base_of<
        std::random_access_iterator_tag,
        IteratorCategoryOf<Container>>;

template<
    typename Container,
    typename std::enable_if<!HaveRandomAccessIterator<Container>::value>::type * = nullptr>
void algorithm(Container &c) {
    //do generic version of algorithm
}

template<
    typename Container,
    typename std::enable_if<HaveRandomAccessIterator<Container>::value>::type * = nullptr>
void algorithm(Container &c) {
    //do random-access version of algorithm
}
```

If C++03 compatibility is required, you can use inheritance rather than type-aliasing, and the boost counterparts to `std::enable_if` and `std::is_base_of`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
static yes& test (typename std::iterator_traits<typename C::iterator*>::random_access_iterator_tag*);
```

SFINAE works this way.

Also, I found the following more elegant:

```
struct yes{};
struct no {};

enum { value = std::is_same<yes, [test-here]>::value };
```

Comment: Whao, so dumb fault from me, thank you very much!
However, it is always have false value, even for std::vector.

Comment: `iterator_traits` has `iterator_category` member typedef. `random_access_iterator_trag` is a tag in the `std` namespace.

Comment: Well, i can't really understand how should i fix this. Now i am trying with this:`static yes& test (typename std::random_access_iterator_tag*);
`
`static const bool value = sizeof(test<std::iterator_traits<typename Container::iterator*>::iterator_category*>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
`
However it give true value for list, and give compile error when i want to use operator[]